# Month Short Names and Regional Format in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have the Windows 10 Display, Apps & websites language as English and my Regional format as Portuguese. In Excel Options > Language the settings are Editing Language: Portuguese; and Display Language: English.

For some reason, I can't make Excel recognize the short name "mmm" of some months (those which differ from the corresponding Portuguese short names) has a date format. For instance: I have a column header which states 'Product Feb 2021 Sales Un' on which I can isolate the 'Feb 2021' part. Next, I would want Excel to recognize the month and calculate the number of days for each month, in order to use this value for a daily avarage metric (as in 'cell reference/number of days'), but everything I tried failed so far. Even when I test a simple formula like '=EOMONTH(TEXT(V39;"[$-0816]mmm aaaa");0)' it returns the #VALUE! error, because it doesn't recognize 'Feb 2021' as a valid date format, as opposed to 'Jan 2021' because in the former the 3 letters of the month are different, while in the late they are the same in EN and in PT.

Comment: please share requested result sample.

Answer (score 0):

Try [$-0016] instead of [$-0816]